# How to diagnose an undefined index in a fresh install of Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, entities, workbench

**Question**:

How do I begin to explore what is causing this error? If this were reporting errors from a contrib module, I would submit a bug report on drupal.org. However, I'm not really sure where I should begin to submit an issue.

**Set up**:

I installed a Drupal 7 instance installed via Quick Drupal

```
drush qd -y d7-mysite
cd mysite/drupal
php -S localhost:8080
```

And immediately installed needed modules via `drush en -y field_collection_tabs workbench workbench_moderation`

- [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) 7.x-1.0-beta11,
- [Field Collection Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_tabs) 7.x-1.0-beta11,
- [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) 7.x-1.2, and
- [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) 7.x-1.4.

**Then the errors:**

After a modicum of configuration to get work bench going and adding a `writer` user, I begin to see these error messages:

> Notice: Undefined index: #contextual_links in
>   contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /drupal/modules/contextual/contextual.module).
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /drupal/modules/contextual/contextual.module).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: #contextual_links in contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /drupal/modules/contextual/contextual.module).
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /drupal/modules/contextual/contextual.module).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: #contextual_links in contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /drupal/modules/contextual/contextual.module).
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /drupal/modules/contextual/contextual.module).

**Location:**

This is coming from a function called `contextual_pre_render_links($element)`

**Other Tidbits**:

- This only happens when the *Authenticated User* creates new node. *Administrator* can create a node with out an error message displaying.
- I'm trying to implement a work-flow system using Workbench *on an inherited site*. I'm trying to understand this process so that I can teach others.

Answer (score 0):

In this development copy I've turned off Contextual (`drush dis contextual`) which of course gets ride of the error message.

I welcome any other answers that might offer a bit of enlightenment to me on this matter. We can live without the Contextual module's functionality but it does add some additional clicks to accomplish certain task.